# Pandas dataframe get first row of each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, row

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,7],
                'value'  : ["first","second","second","first",
                            "second","first","third","fourth",
                            "fifth","second","fifth","first",
                            "first","second","third","fourth","fifth"]})
```

I want to group this by `["id","value"]` and get the first row of each group:

```
        id   value
0        1   first
1        1  second
2        1  second
3        2   first
4        2  second
5        3   first
6        3   third
7        3  fourth
8        3   fifth
9        4  second
10       4   fifth
11       5   first
12       6   first
13       6  second
14       6   third
15       7  fourth
16       7   fifth
```

Expected outcome:

```
    id   value
     1   first
     2   first
     3   first
     4  second
     5  first
     6  first
     7  fourth
```

I tried following, which only gives the first row of the `DataFrame`. Any help regarding this is appreciated.

```
In [25]: for index, row in df.iterrows():
   ....:     df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['id','value']).reset_index().ix[0])
```

Answer (score 428, accepted):

```
>>> df.groupby('id').first()
     value
id        
1    first
2    first
3    first
4   second
5    first
6    first
7   fourth
```

If you need `id` as column:

```
>>> df.groupby('id').first().reset_index()
   id   value
0   1   first
1   2   first
2   3   first
3   4  second
4   5   first
5   6   first
6   7  fourth
```

To get n first records, you can use head():

```
>>> df.groupby('id').head(2).reset_index(drop=True)
    id   value
0    1   first
1    1  second
2    2   first
3    2  second
4    3   first
5    3   third
6    4  second
7    4   fifth
8    5   first
9    6   first
10   6  second
11   7  fourth
12   7   fifth
```

Comment: @Devin you are talking about [DataFrame.first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html). The guy is using [DataFrameGroupBy.first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html)

Answer (score 100):

I'd suggest to use `.nth(0)` rather than `.first()` if you need to get the first row.

The difference between them is how they handle NaNs, so `.nth(0)` will return the first row of group no matter what are the values in this row, while `.first()` will eventually return the first **not** `NaN` value in each column.

E.g.  if your dataset is :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4],
            'value'  : ["first","second","third", np.NaN,
                        "second","first","second","third",
                        "fourth","first","second"]})

>>> df.groupby('id').nth(0)
    value
id        
1    first
2    NaN
3    first
4    first
```

And

```
>>> df.groupby('id').first()
    value
id        
1    first
2    second
3    first
4    first
```

Answer (score 99):

This will give you the second row of each group (**zero indexed**, `nth(0)` is the same as `first()`):

```
df.groupby('id').nth(1)
```

Documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#taking-the-nth-row-of-each-group

Comment: But then it should be nth(0) not nth(1)

Answer (score 24):

If you only need the first row from each group we can do with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), Notice the function default method `keep='first'`.

```
df.drop_duplicates('id')
Out[1027]: 
    id   value
0    1   first
3    2   first
5    3   first
9    4  second
11   5   first
12   6   first
15   7  fourth
```

Answer (score 10):

maybe this is what you want

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['state1','state2'],   ['county1','county2','county3','county4']])
df = pd.DataFrame({'pop': [12,15,65,42,78,67,55,31]}, index=idx)
```

> ```
>                 pop
> state1 county1   12
>        county2   15
>        county3   65
>        county4   42
> state2 county1   78
>        county2   67
>        county3   55
>        county4   31
> ```

```
df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('pop', ascending=False)).groupby(level=0).head(3)

> Out[29]: 
                pop
state1 county3   65
       county4   42
       county2   15
state2 county1   78
       county2   67
       county3   55
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose "first" means you have already sorted your DataFrame as you want.

What I do is :

> df.groupby('id').agg('first')
> I suppose "first" means you have already sorted your DataFrame as you want.
> What I do is :

```
df.groupby('id').agg('first')
     value
id        
1    first
2    first
3    first
4   second
5    first
6    first
7   fourth
```

the nice thing is that you can plug any function you want :

```
df.groupby('id').agg(['first','last','count']))
     value              
     first    last count
id                      
1    first  second     3
2    first  second     2
3    first   fifth     4
4   second   fifth     2
5    first   first     1
6    first   third     3
7   fourth   fifth     2
```

Output DataFrame has MultiIndex columns

```
MultiIndex([('value', 'first'),
            ('value',  'last'),
            ('value', 'count')],
           )
```

Comment: I noted in the comment for another answer that `.first()` should not be used for this purpose. `.nth()` is the method that should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [`take`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.take.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.take) that accepts a list of indices of elements to select:

```
df.groupby('id').take([0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the `'id'` column is of numeric type, such as `int32`/`int64`, one might also use [`groupby.rank()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) as following

```
[In]: df[df.groupby('value')['id'].rank() == 1]
[Out]:
   id   value
0   1   first
6   3   third
7   3  fourth
8   3   fifth
```

If one wants to reset the index, just pass `.reset_index()` such as

```
[In]: df[df.groupby('value')['id'].rank() == 1].reset_index()
[Out]:
   index  id   value
0      0   1   first
1      6   3   third
2      7   3  fourth
3      8   3   fifth
```

If the `index` and `id` columns are not needed

```
[In]: df.drop(['index', 'id'], axis=1, inplace=True)
[Out]:
    value
0   first
1   third
2  fourth
3   fifth
```