# Spark DataFrame Removing duplicates via GroupBy keep first

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the `groupBy` function to remove duplicates from a spark DataFrame. For each group I simply want to take the first row, which will be the most recent one.

I don't want to perform a `max()` aggregation because I know the results are already stored sorted in Cassandra and want to avoid unnecessary computation. See [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067636/pandas-dataframe-get-first-row-of-each-group) using pandas, its exactly what I'm after except in Spark.

```
df = sqlContext.read\
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
            .options(table="table", keyspace="keyspace")\
            .load()\
            .groupBy("key")\
            #what goes here?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `dropDuplicates` should do the job.

Try `df.dropDuplicates(Seq("column")).show`.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/spark-dataframe-select-the-first-row-of-each-group) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually switched to using this approach. `dropDuplicates(['column'])` also works

Comment: @stacksonstacks I would mark this as accepted as it addresses your root problem more directly, but you should also retitle the question.

Comment: @JustinPihony what do you propose for renamed title?

Comment: Get first row of each grouped in DataFrame or similar? @stacksonstacks