# Selecting first few rows based on constant column values

Tags: pandas

I am looking to get records of location (first 2) out of a dataframe where column ID values are constant and then next 2 location records when column value is changed.

```
ID  Location
51699457    LOC000009723262
51699457    LOC000009844932
51699457    LOC000011336522
51699457    LOC000018023392
51699458    LOC000008089735
51699458    LOC000016725720
51699458    LOC000028801236
51699459    LOC000034119383
51699459    LOC000034901728
51699459    LOC000035640991
51699459    LOC000035658463
```

O/P

```
ID  Location
51699457    LOC000009723262
51699457    LOC000009844932
51699458    LOC000008089735
51699458    LOC000016725720
51699459    LOC000035640991
51699459    LOC000035658463
```

any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: df.groupby('ID').head(2).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas dataframe get first row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067636/pandas-dataframe-get-first-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
df.groupby('ID').head(2).reset_index(drop=True)
```