# pandas groupby latest observation for each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  panel dataframe  (ID and time) and want to collect the recent (latest) rows for each ID. Here is the table:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,2,3] , 'Year': [2018,2019,2019,2020] , 'Var1':list("abcd") , 'Var2': list("efgh")})`

[image]

and the end result would be:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe get first row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067636/pandas-dataframe-get-first-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use drop_duplicates:

```
df.sort_values('Year').drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
```

Output:

```
   ID  Year Var1 Var2
1   1  2019    b    f
2   2  2019    c    g
3   3  2020    d    h
```

Comment: Yes, you can use the groupby method like @Roy2012 is doing.

Comment: I am unsure if the `last()` method in @ROy2012 solution is based on time sorting. I wanted to make sure I am getting latest date/year.

Comment: @Roo `df.sort_values('Year').groupby("ID").last()` will ensure this.  Sorting the dataframe appropriate then groupby will do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tail`:

```
df.groupby("ID").tail(1)
```

The output is:

```
   ID  Year Var1 Var2
1   1  2019    b    f
2   2  2019    c    g
3   3  2020    d    h
```

Another alternative is to use `last`:

```
df.groupby("ID").last()
```