# How to select one value from groupby mode?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mode

I need to fill a certain value of null based on mode. I thought by `groupby()` the name and the engine column by mode would solve the problem.

```
engine_df = df.groupby(['Name']).agg({'Engine':pd.Series.mode})[['Engine']].reset_index()
```

output:

```
Name Chevrolet Cruze LTZ AT
Engine [1991.0, 1998.0]
Name: 176, dtype: object
```

Because they have the same quantity, they appear with 2 values, while I need only 1 value.
How to select the first value only?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `first()` method.

```
engine_df = df.groupby(['Name']).agg({'Engine':pd.Series.mode})[['Engine']].first().reset_index()
```

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html) is the documentation on this function.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067636/pandas-dataframe-get-first-row-of-each-group) post has a lot of nice examples of its usage.