# select first value of specific column for each ID in sorted pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for example, my data frame is:

| ID | time | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 14:03:01 | 11 |
| b | 14:03:02 | 7 |
| b | 14:03:15 | 2 |
| c | 14:03:09 | 5 |
| a | 14:03:02 | 9 |
| d | 14:03:17 | 1 |
| a | 14:03:35 | 15 |
| c | 14:03:11 | 8 |

I sort this data frame by time and for each ID I want to get the value of the number column for the earliest time. I know the solution is SQL but now, I get confused to do it for pandas.

| ID | number |
| --- | --- |
| a | 11 |
| b | 7 |
| c | 5 |
| d | 1 |

How can I do these using pandas? (I don't want to use "for loop" .)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe get first row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067636/pandas-dataframe-get-first-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try via `sort_values()` method ,`drop_duplicates()` method and `drop()` method:

```
out=df.sort_values('time').drop_duplicates(subset=['ID']).drop('time',1)
```

**OR**

via `groupby()` and `first()`:

```
out=df.groupby('ID',as_index=False)['number'].first()
```