# Python Pandas: Group by a dataframe based on columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to Group by a dataframe based on columns.

```
        name         month1      month2         month3       .....    month n
    0     john         50         NaN             NaN        .....      .
    1     john         NaN         25             NaN        .....      .
    2     john         NaN        NaN             10         .....      .
    3     mark         NaN         0              NaN        .....      .
    4     mark         15         NaN             NaN        .....      .
    5     paul         NaN        NaN             100        .....      .
```

Final output

```
        name         month1      month2         month3     ....
    0     john         50           25             10      ....
    1     mark         15           0              NaN     ....
    2     paul         NaN          NaN            100     ....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe get first row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067636/pandas-dataframe-get-first-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to Group by

[you said it yourself](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

You can use the `groupby` to post process however you like

Answer (score 0):

Group the dataframe by `name` column then call `first`, and finally reset the index:

```py
>>> df.groupby('name').first().reset_index()

   name  month1  month2  month3
0  john    50.0    25.0    10.0
1  mark    15.0     0.0     NaN
2  paul     NaN     NaN   100.0
```