# Pandas dataframe to get first row but with repeated values in the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067636/pandas-dataframe-get-first-row-of-each-group), but with a twist that the first row might come up in more than one group.

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,2,6,6,6,7,7],
                'value'  : ["first","second","second","first",
                            "second","first","third","fourth",
                            "fifth","second","fifth","first",
                            "first","second","third","fourth","fifth"]})
```

I want to group this by ["id","value"] and get the first row of each group.

```
        id   value
0        1   first
1        1  second
2        1  second
3        2   first
4        2  second
5        3   first
6        3   third
7        3  fourth
8        3   fifth
9        1  second
10       1   fifth
11       2   first
12       6   first
13       6  second
14       6   third
15       7  fourth
16       7   fifth
```

Expected outcome

```
    id   value
     1   first
     2   first
     3   first
     1  second
     2  first
     6  first
     7  fourth
```

I tried the solutions from the linked question, but it works like this:

```
>>> df.groupby('id').first()
     value
id        
1    first
2    first
3    first
6    first
7   fourth
```

Basically, the groupby pulls both groups of 1 and 2 together and only looks at the first one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic. We keep all "first" in value column? Can you further outline _why_ we keep particular rows?

Comment: @HenryEcker OP wants to groupby like `itertools.groupby` and wants to get first value from each of the group. With `itertools.groupy` the grouping would be `[[1,1,1] ,[ 2,2] ,[3,3,3,3] ,[1,1] ,[2], [6,6,6], [7,7]]`

Comment: Every time there's a change in id column, I want to capture that row. Even if that change is to a value we've seen before.

Comment: Ah `df.groupby(df['id'].ne(df['id'].shift()).cumsum()).first()`

Comment: I think the linked question has something I can work with. The shift tool or itertools.groupby would work I think

Comment: @HenryEcker, that works perfectly!

Comment: @HenryEcker, and now that I've understood what it means, it's even more brilliant. Thank you. Wish I could give you a tick!