# Get the first row of each group of unique values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I want to extract from a dataframe only the first row of each value other than one of the columns (pandas) for example:

```
df
   col_A col_B
0      1     x
1      2    xx
2      3    xx
3      4     y
4      5     y
```

to

```
df1
  col_A col_B
0      1     x
1      2    xx
2      4     y
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe get first row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067636/pandas-dataframe-get-first-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first):

```
firsts = df.groupby('col_B', as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
>>> firsts
  col_B  col_A
0     x      1
1    xx      2
2     y      4
```

If the order of the columns is important:

```
firsts = df.loc[df.groupby('col_B', as_index=False).first().index]
```

Output:

```
>>> firsts
   col_A col_B
0      1     x
1      2    xx
2      3    xx
```