# Extract first record of each group dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

There's an excel file with above 200,000 rows and I would like to extract the first row only from each group (the groups are in the third column. I have read the dataset and sorted the values by two columns. Now I just need to create a new dataframe with the first row of each group
[image]

This is sample of the excel file and here's my attempt till now

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Example.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['F. No.', 'Date'], ascending=[True, False])
print(df.head())
```

So I need to extract the four columns starting from `F. No.` to `Emp.` (the most recent records only for each group)

[image]

Comment: How about [Pandas dataframe get first row of each group - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067636/pandas-dataframe-get-first-row-of-each-group)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used this line and it worked well `new_df = df.groupby('F. No.').first()` but the column index changed!!

Comment: @YasserKhalil pass `as_index=False` to `groupby`?

Comment: You might also want to consider just adding `.drop_duplicates('F. No.')` after your sort

Comment: I tried `new_df = df.groupby('F. No.', as_index=False).first()` but the same problem as for the column index point.

Comment: This line `.drop_duplicates('F. No.')` is amazing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Example.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['F. No.', 'Date'], ascending=[True, False])
df_first = df.groupby(['F. No.'], as_index=False).head(1)
```

To make sure that the groupby column does not become an index, pass `as_index=False` kwarg. Note that `.head(1)` works because the data is sorted in the previous line.