# Pandas select all rows from the recent group

Tags: python, pandas

I have df:

```
id    date    group
1      1.1    3
1      2.1    3
1      3.1    5
1      4.1    5
2      5.2    2
2      6.2    1
2      9.2    1
2      12.2    1 
3      15.3   15
3      20.3    20
```

I want for each group to get all the rows from the recent date . that means that in this df id 2 is the recent group(according to the date column) so I want to filter to display only rows of id 2.
So the desire output:

```
id    date    group
1      3.1    5
1      4.1    5
2      6.2    1
2      9.2    1
2      12.2    1 
3      20.3    20
```

thanks

Comment: It looks like you should provide a complete example with the date column **and the matching expected output**

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question. You have to help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this needs 2 steps.

1. get last group per id.
2. filter df by 1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.array([[1,1.1,3],[1,2.1,3],[1,3.1,5],[1,4.1,5],[2,5.2,2],[2,6.2,1],[2,9.2,1],[2,12.2,1,],[3,15.3,15],[3,20.3,20]]),
    columns=['id', 'date', 'group']
    )
```

step 1. get last group per id

I referred to the following address : [Pandas dataframe get first row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20067636/19550638)

```
#step 1
lastgroup = df.groupby('id').last()
lastgroup = lastgroup.reset_index()[['id', 'group']]
```

lastgroup is :

```
>>> lastgroup
    id  group
0  1.0    5.0
1  2.0    1.0
2  3.0   20.0
```

step 2. filter df by lastgroup by using pd.merge :

```
#step 2
result = pd.merge(left=df, right=lastgroup)
```

result may be

```
>>> result
    id  date  group
0  1.0   3.1    5.0
1  1.0   4.1    5.0
2  2.0   6.2    1.0
3  2.0   9.2    1.0
4  2.0  12.2    1.0
5  3.0  20.3   20.0
```

Comment: in the case I have multi different id, I want to each id get the recent group. sorry I edit the question

Comment: sorry I edit the question

Comment: Please update your answer and use correct PEP8 code formating. Your code is hard to read.

Comment: @nena I updated the code to match the changed question.