# guys, Is there a way to get the firs row in a group dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

this is a code i wrote, but the output is too big, over 6000, how do i get the first result for each year

df_year = df.groupby('release_year')['genres'].value_counts()

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067636/pandas-dataframe-get-first-row-of-each-group)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from a small correction concerning variable name:
*value_counts* returns a **Series** (not DataFrame), so you should
not use name starting from *df*.

Assume that the variable holding this Series is *gen*.

Then, one of possible solutions is:

```
result = gen.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda grp:
    grp.droplevel(0).sort_values(ascending=False).head(1))
```

Initially you wrote that you wanted the most popular genre in each year,
so I sorted each group in descending order and returned the first
row from the current group.